# Junit babysiter kata

Tags: java, testing, junit, calculator

I'm having a bit of trouble running test for the babysitter kata on java/junit. My test keeps telling me that the expected was 16 but it was actually 60. I don't know where my math is going wrong to get this output. I would like for my expected to match my actual for my second test.

```
public Object calculatePay() {
        int potentialPayBefore10 = 12;
        int potentialPayAfter10 = 8;

        // $12 hour * 5 hours worked
        potentialPayBefore10 = 12 * 5;
        potentialPayAfter10 = 8 * 2;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (potentialPayBefore10 < 60) {
            return potentialPayAfter10;
        } else
            return potentialPayBefore10;

    }

}


public class DaysWorked {

    /*
     * Story: As a babysitter In order to get paid for 1 night of work I want to
     * calculate my nightly charge
     */

    // Project Goal: Create test to show Mellie being paid

    // Start with calc time for 1 hour of work
    @Test
    public void calculatepayforworkafterstarttimeat12hourly() {
        // 5 is hours worked if start at 5 pm til 10p
        MellieWageCalculator potentialPay = new MellieWageCalculator(5);
        // assert equals gives -> (expected, actual)
        assertEquals(60, potentialPay.calculatePay());
    }

    @Test
    public void calculatepayforworkafter10pmat8hourly() {
        // 2 hours worked if start at 10pm til 12 pm
        MellieWageCalculator potentialPay = new MellieWageCalculator(2);
        assertEquals(16, potentialPay.calculatePay());

    }

}
```

Comment: Your calculatePay() method is always returning 60, so the assertEquals fails when you compare to 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `@sirandy` mentioned your code seems to be static, so it produces the same result for both the test cases. Adding a private class variable to store the pay dynamically might help pass the tests

```
private int hoursWorked= 0;
public MellieWageCalculator(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.hoursWorked= i;
}

public Object calculatePay() {
    int potentialPayBefore10 = 12;
    int potentialPayAfter10 = 8;

    // $12 hour * 5 hours worked
    potentialPayBefore10 = 12 * hoursWorked;
    potentialPayAfter10 = 8 * hoursWorked;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (potentialPayBefore10 < 60) {
        return potentialPayAfter10;
    } else
        return potentialPayBefore10;

}
```

Comment: This worked!!! I can't believe I missed making it private...jeez louis! Thank you!!!